# KafkaConsumer get empty records from remote kafka server but get records when running the same program in the kafka server machine

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I am using Kafka server 3.3.1 and java package Kafka-Clients 3.3.1.

I have a simple KafkaConsumer program as below:

```
        Properties consumerProperties= new Properties();
        // fake ip address
        consumerProperties.put("bootstrap.servers", "220.220.220.220:9092");

        consumerProperties.put("group.id", "TestConsumerGroup");
        consumerProperties.put("key.deserializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer");
        consumerProperties.put("value.deserializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer");

        consumerProperties.put("auto.offset.reset", "earliest");
        consumerProperties.put("client.id", "remote1");

        KafkaConsumer consumer = new KafkaConsumer(consumerProperties);

        String topicName="quickstart-events";
        consumer.subscribe(Collections.singletonList(topicName));

        Duration duration = Duration.ofSeconds(10);
        int epoch=1;
        while(true){

            System.out.println(epoch++);

            ConsumerRecords<String, String> records=consumer.poll(5000);
            consumer.seekToBeginning(consumer.assignment());

            System.out.println("records count:"+records.count());
            for(var record: records){
                System.out.printf("topic=%s, partition=%d, offset=%d, key=%s, value=%s\n", record.topic(),
                record.partition(), record.offset(), record.key(), record.value());
            }
        }
```

Firstly, I run this program in the machine A(this can access kafka server machien with ssh) which is a different machine with kafka server machine.
consumerProperties.put("bootstrap.servers", "220.220.220.220:9092");// public ip 220.220.220.220:9092 this is the kafka server machine.

Then the records count always is empty no matter the timeout duration. By the way, if I call listTopics() method then I can get the result successfully in machine A.

Secondly, I deploy this program in the kafka server machine. Then I can read the message records successfully.

Do you know the reason? Thanks
Then

The expect result is that I should get the same result with I run this program in the kafka server machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Add a log4j.properties file to your client to see connection issues
2. Make sure `advertised.listeners=PLAINTEXT://220.220.220.220:9092` on the server
3. Test first with other tools like `kafka-console-consumer` or `kcat`

Comment: Thanks, actually you are right, I missed the `advertised.listeners` config